# Is my plan for embedding a mirror in a tile wall ok?

Tags: tile, backsplash

Doing a bath remodel, and found this photo of a backsplash that appeals to me. I like the built-in tile-framed mirror.

Seems easy to achieve. I would appreciate some input on my plans:

- Install 1/2" cement board on studs above vanity. Install 1/4" cement
  board exact size of mirror on top of 1/2" cement board. E.g., cut a
  18" by 24" piece of 1/4" cement board.
- Attach mirror to cement board
  using adhesive.
- Frame around mirror with something like pencil
  molding.
- Tile the wall.

[image]

Comment: Questions asking for "some input" can be considered too broad. What particular aspect of your plan has you concerned?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd bother with the 1/4" layer. Wouldn't you want the mirror flush with or behind the tile plane?

Comment: @isherwood.  You’re probably right about that.

Answer (score 1):

Mirrors get broken.  Mirrors lose their silvering on the back.  Neither is a likely event, but in this case a very expensive or time consuming one.  As a general rule I hate to create situations where fixing it later is difficult.

For this reason were it my project:

- Don't attach the mirror to the substrate with adhesive or thinset.  I don't know what the chemistry between either and the thin layer of aluminum on the back of the glass would be. If you do removing the mirror will be difficult.
- Buy a mirror with holes drilled in it.  Buy a set of the cute rosettes and attach the mirror directly to the wall.
- Frame the mirror in a complementary wood, and attach THAT to the wall.  The outer edge of the frame should be raked about 5 degrees so that it can be removed from the tile when necessary.

Comment: Oh, but the fully integrated look is so cool it's worth the risk.

Comment: I hear your concerns, and those went through my mind.  But the previous mirror was there for 35 years without a problem.  Maybe the solution is to not skimp on the mirror.